# Put a logo next to a title with CSS Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use Bootstrap to put my logo next to my website name. I am trying to use Bootstrap because I want it to scale as the webpage changes in size, but I can not figure out how to do it correctly. I am new to Bootstrap, so this might be a simple fix.

I am trying to make my website look like this:
[image]

See how there is a horse logo image next to NOMAD RIDES at the top of the webpage. Here is my current html:

```html
<div id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" id="headerDiv">
         <h1 class="col-4 align-middle">Nomad Rides</h1>
         <img class="img-fluid col-2 align-middle" src="logo.png">
    </div>         
</div>
```

It looks okay on certain screen sizes. But, I want to set a maximum size of the logo and title. So, once it hits minimum of 500px screen size (i.e. when someone views it on a big desktops screen), the text and image size should stop growing. I know a media query is probably the way to do it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: why don't you just put the `<img>` in the `<h1>`?

Comment: Well that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply put the `<img>` inside the `<h1>`:

```
<div id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" id="headerDiv">
         <h1 class="col-4 align-middle"><img class="img-fluid col-2 align-middle" src="logo.png">Nomad Rides</h1>
    </div>         
</div>
```